# How to plot a graph?

Tags: plotting

I am a beginner, I went through the help option to plot this graph, but I couldn't plot it, 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica Stack Exchange.  Just a heads up, you may not get much traction with your question because it appears you are asking people to do your work for you.  Can you at least tell us what you tried and what resources you have looked at?

Comment: look at `ListPlot` there are examples there.

Answer (score 2):

This code should get you started.

```
time = {0, 5, 10, 40}
speed = {0, 55, 150, 200}
plot = AssociationThread[time -> speed]
ListLinePlot[plot, AxesLabel -> {"time", "speed"}]
```

[image]

Comment: How is that code "getting started"?  What more is there left to do?

Comment: As a newbie myself, I am keenly aware of the feeling of not even knowing where to start with coding or asking a question on SE.  There are times where I looked at example after example of similar problems, but couldn't decipher the code, or understand why certain parameters were being included/excluded.  Of course a week or two later, after things clicked, I realized how elementary the problem was.  I appreciated people pointing me in the right direction even on simple questions.  The code above isn't the "right" answer to the problem, but it should get the OP along the right track.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and I will try to focus more on the given examples